# why data return from ajax upload file is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to upload file with ajax file upload. File will be uploaded and address of this file is return by server. But data is undefined.

[jquery-2.2.3.min.js](http://pishroafzarco.com/test/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js) and 
[ajaxFileupload](http://pishroafzarco.com/test/js/ajaxfileupload.js)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxfileupload.js"></script>``
```

---

```
<input type="file" id="upload_pic_file1" name="upload_pic_file1"/>
<input type="hidden" id="enrolment_pic1"  name="enrolment_pic1"/>
```

---

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
  url: domainName +'/UploadServlet',
  secureuri: false,
  fileElementId: "upload_pic_file1",
  dataType: 'JSON',
  cache: false,
  beforeSend: function () {},
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data);//data is undefined!
$("#enrolment_pic1").val(data);
}
});
```

I don't know where problem is. There is no error!
Server is on another IP address.

Comment: does server actually return any data?

Comment: whats returning from "domainName +'/UploadServlet'"?

Comment: @alt255 server code is correct, but I think client doen't receive any thing from server.

Comment: @romaltandel file name that is uploaded for example p123.png or if size of file is big, server return "big".

Comment: Cross domain request is not supported by XHR